# Bokeh CustomJS Passing Array of Glyphs

Tags: javascript, python, bokeh, bokehjs

I am trying to create multiple figures that sow various info about countries. On top of that, I am trying to have set of buttons that would hide plots of countries across all figures. When using CustomJS callback, I am trying to pass ColumnDataSource with individual countries as columns with respective glyphs in the column. The ColumnDataSource looks like below:

> {'index': array([0, 1], dtype=int64), 'US':
>   array([GlyphRenderer(id='1038', ...), GlyphRenderer(id='1157', ...)],
>   dtype=object), 'United Arab Emirates': array([nan, nan]), 'United
>   Kingdom': array([GlyphRenderer(id='1079', ...),
>   GlyphRenderer(id='1198', ...)]}

I then try to pass into CustomJS like below:

```
callback = CustomJS(args={'source':source}, code="""..."""
```

However, console in in google chrome shows following error. I am struggling to understand if it is not iterable, because I have objects in each column, or because columns are strings?

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: (intermediate value)(intermediate value)(intermediate value) is not iterable

When I pass a column directly, it works as I would expect. However, I am trying to put in many countries.

```
callback = CustomJS(args={'source':source.data['US']}, code="""..."""
```

Thank you very much,
Tomas

Comment: Your data looks really strange. Are you putting renderers into the data source? If so, I don't think it's officially supported in any way.

Comment: Thanks for the color! Yes, when I am adding line to figure, I store it in the array. In the second piece of code where I pass only the US column, it then allows me to use following in JavaScript to hide desired lines `var us_glyphs = source; us_glyphs[0].visible = false; us_glyphs[1].visible = false;` Is there a way to make glyphs non-visible by glyph id? Thanks!

Comment: Putting renderers in a ColumnDataSource is definitely not supported.

Comment: I see, thank you! Any workaround, such as using 2D array, that would come to mind? Or referencing by IDs?

Comment: Can you not passed them named individually in the `args` dict?

Comment: Also, they can be put in a regular Python dict or list and only then passed to `args`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed in comments, I could've passed dictionaries. Clearly true and I was overthinking the problem by passing ColumnDataSource.

The problem was solved by looping thru all glyphs as in an example below that makes all glyphs invisible.

```
callback = CustomJS(args={'source':one_line, 'countries': all_countries}, code="""
var arr_glyphs = source;
var arr_countries = countries;
var index;
var index_country;                     

for (index = 0; index < arr_countries.length; ++index) {
    for (index_country = 0; index_country < arr_countries[index].length; ++index_country) {
        arr_glyphs[arr_countries[index]][index_country].visible = false;
    };
};""")
```

Thank you for your help!